# Frontend App shows a blank page if I scale up kubernetes deployment to 3

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kops

I have a frontend application that works perfectly fine when I have just one instance of the application running in a kubernetes cluster. But when I scale up the deployment to have 3 replicas it shows a blank page on the first load and then after the refresh, it loads the page. As soon as I scale down the app to 1, it starts loading fine again.
Here is the what the console prints in the browser.

> hub.xxxxx.me/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://hub.xxxxxx.me/static/js/main.5a4e61df.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

[image]
Adding the screenshot as well. Any ideas what might be the case. I know it is an infrastructure issue since it happens only when I scale the application.

One thing I noticed is that 2 pods have a different js file that the other pod.

> 2 pods have this file - build/static/js/main.b6aff941.js
>
> The other pod has this file - build/static/js/main.5a4e61df.js

I think the mismatch is causing the problem. Any Idea how to fix this mismatch issue so that the pods always have the same build?

Comment: I expect all pods should have the same information, Any reason why `main.b6aff941.js' script available only two pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the mismatch is causing the problem. Any Idea how to fix this mismatch issue so that the pods always have the same build?

Yes, this is actually pretty common in a build where those resources change like that. You actually won't want to use the traditional rolling-update mechanism, because your deployment is closer to a blue-green one: only one "family" of Pods should be in service at a time, else the **html** from Pod 1 is served but the subsequent request for the **javascript** from Pod 2 is 404

There is also the pretty grave risk of a browser having a cached copy of the HTML, but kubernetes can't -- by itself -- help you with that.

One pretty reasonable solution is to scale the Deployment to one replica, do the image patch, wait for the a-ok, then scale them back up, so there is only one source of truth for the application running in the cluster at a time. A rollback would look very similar: scale 1, rollback the deployment, scale up

An alternative mechanism would be to use label patching, to atomically switch the `Service` (and presumably thus the `Ingress`) over to the new Pods all at once, but that would require having multiple copies of the application in the cluster at the same time, which for a front-end app is likely more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: What do you mean by an image patch ?

Comment: `kubectl set image deploy $the_deploy "the_con=the/new/image:tag"` which will trigger a new `rollout` just like you had patched the `Deployment` itself (which is, of course, what that command does behind the scenes)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. This made me think of another way to tackle it. Correct me if I am wrong. I have a gitlab runner that builds the image which then kubernetes pulls and deploys. I was building the source code while deploying the image, which was a poor design on my part. I will just create a prebuilt code and then just run the code during the deployment process. I think this should solve the problem as well. Any thoughts ?

Comment: That's a bigger question than is healthy for comments, but the tl;dr is yes, the image that goes into the cluster should be `FROM nginx` and just ship the html accompanying assets that were _built_ by CI, otherwise you run the risk of some transient failure bombing the rollout of a static website, which would be super weird